# Object reference error trying to use RenderPartial

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a main view using a `ViewModel`. Inside the `ViewModel` I do this **(Edited to show complete `ViewModel`)**:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.ViewModels
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public ModelOne ModelOne { get; set; }
        public ModelTwo ModelTwo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

On my main view I do this **(EDIT: Added `@Html.Hidden` code)**:

```
@using MyNameSpace.ViewModels
@using MyNameSpace.Models
@model MyViewModel

...
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost())
{ 
    @Html.Hidden("myData", new MvcSerializer()
        .Serialize(Model, SerializationMode.Signed))
....
<div>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_MyCheckBox", 
        Model.ModelTwo, new ViewDataDictionary());}
</div>
}
....
```

My partial view is:

```
@using MyNameSpace.Models
@model ModelTwo
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.MyCheckBox)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <select multiple="multiple" id="@Html.FieldIdFor(x =>
                x.MyCheckBox)" name="@Html.FieldNameFor(x =>
                x.MyCheckBox)">

                @foreach (MyEnum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
                {
                    var selected = Model.MyCheckBox.Contains(item); //ERROR HERE
                    <option value="@((int)item)" @if (selected)
                        {<text>selected="selected"</text>}>
                        @T(item.ToString())
                    </option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I am getting the `Object reference not set to an instance ...` error and am not sure how to correct it.

Originally, I had that `<fieldset>` inside my main view and was getting that error. I thought it was because of the two models and that's why I placed it in a partial view. But only to discover I am running into the same problem.

I am not setting the `MyCheckBox` in my partial view on the line `var selected = Model.MyCheckBox.Contains(item);` properly.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT (Adding `MyCheckBox` code)**

Here is `MyCheckBox` inside *ModelOne.cs*:

```
[Mandatory(ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one option")]
[Display(Name = "Please select one ore more options")]
[MySelector]
public virtual int MyCheckBox { get; set; }
```

And here it is inside *ModelTwo.cs*:

```
private IList<MyEnum> _myEnum;
public IList<MyEnum> MyCheckBox
{
    get
    {
        if (_myEnum== null)
        {
            _myEnum= new List<MyEnum>();
            foreach (MyEnumitem in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
            {
                if (((MyEnum)Record.MyCheckBox& item) == item)
                    _myEnum.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return _myEnum;
    }
    set
    {
        _myEnum= value;
        Record.MyCheckBox= 0;
        foreach (var item in value)
        {
            Record.MyCheckBox|= (int)item;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, I am using Orchard (hence the `Record`) which, in turn, uses NHibernate. I don't believe that is relevant, but I could be wrong. The `MyCheckBox` code is using `[Flags]` attribute of `enum` and storing the value as an `int` in the DB (hence the proxy).  Here is what the `enum` would look like:

*MyEnum.cs*:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Display(Name="Name 1")]
    Enum1 = 1,
    [Display(Name="Name 2")]
    Enum2 = 2,
    [Display(Name="Name 3")]
    Enum3 = 4,
    [Display(Name="Name 4")]
    Enum4 = 8,
    [Display(Name="Name 5")]
    Enum5 = 16
}
```

*MyController.cs*

```
private MyViewModel myData;
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var serialized = Request.Form["myData"];
    if (serialized != null) //Form was posted containing serialized data
    {
    myData= (MyViewModel)new MvcSerializer().Deserialize
        (serialized, SerializationMode.Signed);
        TryUpdateModel(myData);
    }
    else
        myData= (MyViewModel)TempData["myData"] ?? new MyViewModel();
    TempData.Keep();
}
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
        TempData["myData"] = myData;
}
```

Then in the particular `Action` within *MyController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Step5(string backButton, string nextButton)
{
    if (backButton != null)
        return RedirectToAction("Step4");
    else if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("Confirm");
    else
        return View(myData);
    }
```

Comment: What's null, Model or MyCheckBox?

Comment: @Forty-Two Honestly, can't tell in debug mode. I thought it was the model and I did `ModelTwo ModelTwo = new ModelTwo();` to no avail, so unless that was wrong I have to assume MyCheckBox.

Comment: I was about to answer your question, can you please post the definition for MyViewModel and myCheckBox?

Comment: @BishnuPaudel Added code. Some of it might not be relevant. I left out code for `[MySelector]`

Comment: @REMESQ, are you setting ModelTwo in ViewModel's instance in the controller before rendering your main View? Can you please post your controller's code which renders your main view?

Comment: @BishnuPaudel It's a little convoluted, but I just added the code. Using `Serializable` from MvcFutures.

Comment: Thanks, Looks like ModelTwo's value is not set in the controller's method Step5, can you try 'myData.ModelTow=new ModelTwo();'. Good luck.

Comment: @BishnuPaudel That's throwing another `object reference` error since I am serializing in the `@Html.Hidden` code (which I added to the main view above).